# ValueBoxEditorDecorator<String> does not show errors

Tags: gwt

I was under the impression that ValueBoxEditorDecorator would display errors to the right of the text box. I am running this code. When errors are picked up, I get a alert box, but nothing is shown for ValueBoxEditorDecorator.

```java
public class AddressEditor extends Composite implements Editor<Address>, HasEditorErrors<Address> 
{
    private static final Binder binder = GWT.create(Binder.class);
    @UiField ValueBoxEditorDecorator<String> name;

    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, AddressEditor> {
    }

    public AddressEditor() {
        initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void showErrors(List<EditorError> errors) {
        name.showErrors(errors);
        if (errors.size()>0)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(EditorError e : errors)
            {
                sb.append(e.getMessage());
            }
            Window.alert(sb.toString());
        }
    }
```

This is the xml ui.

```java
<e:ValueBoxEditorDecorator ui:field="name">
    <e:valuebox>
        <g:TextBox/>
    </e:valuebox>
</e:ValueBoxEditorDecorator>
```

EDIT:

This is my validation detection code. Perhaps I am erasing some data about the path files of the errors.

```java
a = editorDriver.flush();

ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure().buildValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

Set<ConstraintViolation<Address>> violations = validator.validate(a);

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations2 = (Set<ConstraintViolation<?>>) (Set) violations;

editorDriver.setConstraintViolations(violations2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The problem was that my JSR303 annotations where on the private fields, rather than on the getter.